# Python - calculations with more than one splited serial data

Tags: python, class, methods, arduino-uno

1. I use Arduino to receive data from sensors (4 types of data : humidity, temperature, photocell and milliseconds)
2. Datas comes like this : xx xx xx xxxx in the serial buffer. (data space data space etc...)
3. I split this line in order to isolate each data because I want to make individual calculations for each sensor.
4. Calculation for each sensor consist on : ((latest_data) - (data_of_previous_line), latest_data) in order to get a tuple for each sensor. I want all the sensors tuples appearing in the same line.
5. Doing this with 1 sensor and 1 method (`calculate()`) is working fine but it doesn't work if I add a second sensor in `sensors()` object !

QUESTION : how to make all this working with at least 2 sensors data ?

(the code below is working perfectly with 1 "splited" sensor data).

Thanks in advance.

```
class _share:

    def __init__(self):
        self.last_val = [0 for i in range(2)]

    def calculate(self, val):
        self.last_data = val
        self.last_val = [self.last_data] + self.last_val[:-1]
        diff = reduce(operator.__sub__, self.last_val)
        print (diff, val)
        return (diff, val)

share = _share()
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyS1', 9600, timeout=0.1)


def sensors():

    while True:
        try:
            time.sleep(0.01)
            ser.flushInput()
            reception = ser.readline()
            receptionsplit = reception.split()

            sensor_milli = receptionsplit[3]
            sensor_pho_1 = receptionsplit[2]
            sensor_tem_1 = receptionsplit[1]
            sensor_hum_1 = receptionsplit[0]

            int_sensor_milli = int(sensor_milli)
            int_sensor_pho_1 = int(sensor_pho_1)
            int_sensor_tem_1 = int(sensor_tem_1)
            int_sensor_hum_1 = int(sensor_hum_1)

            a = int_sensor_milli
            b = int_sensor_pho_1
            c = int_sensor_tem_1
            d = int_sensor_hum_1

            return str(share.calculate(b))
        except:
            pass
        time.sleep(0.1)

f = open('da.txt', 'ab')
while 1:
    arduino_sensor = sensors()
    f.write(arduino_sensor)
    f.close()
    f = open('da.txt', 'ab')
```

Comment: Your loop will only run once. The return statement inside the loop breaks it. Is this expected behaviour?

Comment: On my side the return is not breaking the loop.

Comment: But I am open to any solution even if I have to modify my code ... ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use different *share* instance for each sensor otherwise the calculations will be wrong. So use share_a, share_b, share_c and share_d for a, b, c and d respectively for example. Now if I understand this correctly, you can return all the sensors at once by changing your return to:

```
return [ str(share_a.calculate(a)), str(share_b.calculate(b)), str(share_c.calculate(c)), str(share_d.calculate(d)) ]
```

The above would return a list containing all 4 sensors and then in your main method you can change to:

```
arduino_sensor = sensors()
sensor_string ="a:%s b:%s c:%s d:%s"%( arduino_sensor[0], arduino_sensor[1], arduino_sensor[2], arduino_sensor[3] )
print sensor_string # single line screen print of all sensor data 
f.write( sensor_string )
```

I hope that is helpful.

Comment: For the second part of your answer... it is to place inside the method ? or inside the while  1 ?

Comment: Inside the while 1, where you have the line arduino_sensor=sensors()

Comment: I get this : f.write(arduino_sensor)
TypeError: must be string or buffer, not list

Comment: Well, I expected that you know how to convert that to a string no? Wait let me update the answer.

Comment: How did that go? If it is fine, please accept this as the answer to assign due credit. Thanks.

Comment: I debuged to check where is wrong... So it seems that again 1 sensor is ok but big problems with all sensors at same time. Do u think it could come in conflict with the print of calculate() that is made only for 1 sensor ?

Comment: Which sensor is ok ? a, b, c, or d? or are you referring to an additional physical sensor?

Comment: Sensor "a" is ok. But it is ok with also with the rest of sensors as long as they are alone in the print. Thats the purpose of my question today.

Comment: The other obvious problem i can see is that you are reusing share. You need to have a different share for each sensor otherwise self._lastdata and self._lastvalue would be wrong and you would get the wrong results. So use a share_a, share_b, share_c and a share_d respectively for a, b, c and d sensors.

Comment: I tried already to put additional method inside share but did not work.But I did not try what you say. Coming back to tell you result...

Comment: Ok. I tried with sensors a and b and datas are appearing with correct calculations. I get 2 tuples BUT they come in 2 separate lines not in a single one.

Comment: Do you mean they are printed on the screen in 2 separate lines or are they written into the file in 2 separate lines?

Comment: In file i get all datas in a single line (I would like to get 1 line in screen = 1 line in text) and in screen i get 2 lines (1 for each sensor tuple) and i would like to get all sensor tuples in same line.

Comment: I already updated the answer for this, have a look. just above f.write(...) use "print sensor_string" (without the quotes). and remove the print call from your share class.

Comment: screen is ok ! but not file... I guess it is to add something like \n somewhere but since this was not part of my question I consider your answer as a good one ! thanks a lot siphr !

Comment: Thanks alot could you also please vote it up? Thank you.

Comment: Yes i did. Thanks again !